# Python - How can I call methods of super class from child class instance?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, overriding, super

When child class has a method with same name with the method in parent class, the method of child class overrides the method of parent class.

In the definition of child class, it is possible to access the method of parent class by `super()`.

Then, Does it possible to access the method of parent class from child class Instance?

```py
class Person:
    def print(self):
        print("Message from Person")

class Student(Person):
    def print(self):
        print("Message from Student")\

s = Student()
# Method of Student Class Instance
s.print()  # Output: "Message from Student"

# I want to call method "print" of Person
# from student Instance
# How can I call it?
s.super().print()  # ERROR
super(s).print()  # ERROR
```

Comment: If you want both methods to be easily accesible, why override them? Just give them different names.

Comment: can you paste the error so we understand better?

Comment: @mapf Thanks for your help. I know that it could be solved easily as you said. But, I just wonder whether it is possible or not. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is absolutely no way to access the parent class in any other way, I guess you could do this, but I would absolutely **not** recommend it:

```
class Person:
    def print(self):
        print("Message from Person")


class Student(Person):
    def print(self):
        print("Message from Student")


s = Student()
# Method of Student Class Instance
s.print()  # Output: "Message from Student"
s.__class__.__base__.print(s.__class__.__base__)  # Output: "Message from Person"
```

You have to understand that this is super hacky, and that you are not calling the method of an instance, as it is the case with `s.print()`, but you are calling the method of an uninstantiated class, a method that is not a `classmethod` (or `staticmethod` for that matter) and pass it the class as an argument (i.e. the `self` argument). It's very different syntax.

And again, it makes much more sense to give the methods different names instead of overriding them.